# Kotlin overload Int operator in class for DSL statement

Tags: kotlin, operator-overloading, dsl

In next code I'm trying to write DSL, which allowed some constructions for **hands** of some robot.
It should have syntax below, which I should use in outer context for RobotBuilder class:

```
robot {
    hands {
        plastik width 3
        load = light - medium
    }
    head {
        ...
    }
    etc...
}
```

The problem is in string `load = light - medium`. It's do nothing, but Robot created. What I do? Just overload minus operator for Int. For me when Kotlin compiler see expression of  =  -  it should use overloaded operator. What I am doing wrong?

Should I create special class like LoadClassBuilder with only one attribute of type LoadClass and then overload minus operator in HandsBuilder for  -  and change types for load, light and medium or problem in outer context of my DSL?

```
class HandsBuilder {
    var material: Material = Metal(0)
    var minLoad: LoadClass = LoadClass.Medium
    var maxLoad: LoadClass = LoadClass.Medium

    val plastik: Plastik = Plastik(0)
    val metal: Metal = Metal(0)

    infix fun Metal.width(width: Int) {
        material = Metal(width)
    }

    infix fun Plastik.width(width: Int) {
        material = Plastik(width)
    }

    var load: Int = 0
    val light: Int = 1
    val medium: Int = 2

    operator fun Int.minus(other: Int): Int {
        println("minus call")
        minLoad = LoadClass.values()[this]
        println(this)
        maxLoad = LoadClass.values()[other]
        println(other)
        return 1
    }

    fun build() = Hands(material, minLoad, maxLoad)
}
```

Update 1:

```
fun hands(init: HandsBuilder.() -> Unit) {
    handsParamInRobotBuilderClass = HandsBuilder().apply(init).build()
}
```

Comment: How your `hands` function looks like?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь updated. If I'm using <LoadClass> type for light and medium in HandsBuilder class and overload minus operator for such types then it works.

Comment: Oh, I got it. If you defining extension member which clashes with existing class member, the latter with take precedence. So it's impossible to override `minus` for `Int`; you need to use type which doesn't have `minus` method to implement that syntax.

Comment: @МихаилНафталь thank you =(